# How to remove an unwanted file before signing app in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I am getting this error when attempting to upload my iOS file to the app store: 
"invalid bundle structure - the binary file is not permitted"

I found that there is a .dylib file being added (for a reason I cannot work out) to the app and this is not allowed.

If I delete the file myself I have a signing error when uploading.

Any solutions? I found some answers which referred to deletion during the building phase in xcode but could not manage to do it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you use xcodebuild to produce the same results as building your code from Xcode?  Does the dylib get added then?

Comment: What's the error message exactly? Which file is it complaining about and does that file gets added during build or come in as part of third-party framework you're using?

Comment: The issue have happened if you have added the library in "Copy Bundle Resources" instead of "Link Binary with Libraries". In this case, you might have multiple executable in bundle structure which can cause this issue.

Comment: @manman The full error is: ERROR ITMS-90171: Invalid Bundle Structure - The binary file MySampleApp.app/libswiftRemoteMirror.dylib is not permitted. Your app cant contain standalone executables or libraries, other than the CFBundleExecutable of supported bundles. Refer to the Bundle Programming Guide at https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure for information on the iOS app bundle structure.

Comment: @ShaheenMBasheer There is no mention of any file seemingly connected to the .dylib file in copy bundle resources

Comment: @AgnosticDev No! It does not get added in this case. What does that mean therefore?

Comment: Using xcodebuild from the command line does not add the dylib, but archiving the project from Xcode does?  Is that what I understand?

Comment: No, building from xcode adds it. Archiving does not.

Comment: To resolve this I would try and see what Xcode is adding extra that xcodebuild is not from the command line.  You are archive and then creating an IPA from the command line, correct?

Comment: Correct. How can I see what Xcode is adding?

Comment: OK, that is strange.  Xcode should only be adding what you tell it to in you build phases and build settings.  You can see all dylibs it adds while archiving.  Are you able to sign and upload from the command line?

Comment: @ace Just to be clear, if you archive with Xcode and then export it for submission to Apple, would you see that file inside the produced ipa? and if you're using xcodebuild, please try to add `-exportOptionsPlist` as suggested [here](https://medium.com/@zonble/upgrade-to-xcode-8-716cde2bb19d)